# Removing dataframe outliers in R with `boxplot.stats`

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, outliers

I'm relatively new at R, so please bear with me.

I'm using the Ames dataset (full description of dataset [here](http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v19n3/decock.pdf); link to dataset download [here](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v19n3/decock/AmesHousing.xls)).

I'm trying to create a subset data frame that will allow me to run a linear regression analysis, and I'm trying to remove the outliers using the `boxplot.stats` function. I created a frame that will include my samples using the following code:

```
regressionFrame <- data.frame(subset(ames_housing_data[,c('SalePrice','GrLivArea','LotArea')] , BldgType == '1Fam'))
```

My next objective was to remove the outliers, so I tried to subset using a `which()` function:

```
regressionFrame <- regressionFrame[which(regressionFrame$GrLivArea != boxplot.stats(regressionFrame$GrLivArea)$out),]
```

Unfortunately, that produced the

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

error. Does anyone know a better way to approach this, ideally using the `which()` subsetting function? I'm assuming it would include some form of `lapply()`, but for the life of me I can't figure out how. (I figure I can always learn fancier methods later, but this is the one I'm going for right now since I already understand it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice use with `boxplot.stats`.

You can not test SAFELY using `!=` if `boxplot.stats` returns you more than one outliers in `$out`. An analogy here is `1:5 != 1:3`. You probably want to try `!(1:5 %in% 1:3)`.

```
regressionFrame <- subset(regressionFrame,
                          subset = !(GrLivArea %in% boxplot.stats(GrLivArea)$out))
```

What I mean by SAFELY, is that `1:5 != 1:3` gives a wrong result with a warning, but `1:6 != 1:3` gives a wrong result without warning. The warning is related to the *recycling rule*. In the latter case, `1:3` can be recycled to have the same length of `1:6` (that is, the length of `1:6` is a multiple of the length of `1:3`), so you will be testing with `1:6 != c(1:3, 1:3)`.

---

A simple example.

```
x <- c(1:10/10, 101, 102, 103)  ## has three outliers: 101, 102 and 103
out <- boxplot.stats(x)$out  ## `boxplot.stats` has picked them out
x[x != out]  ## this gives a warning and wrong result
x[!(x %in% out)]  ## this removes them from x
```