# Delete outliers

Tags: r, outliers

I have a large data set with over 2000 observations. The data involves toxin concentrations in animal tissue. My response variable is `myRESULT` and I have multiple observations per `ANALYTE` of interest. I need to remove the outliers, as defined by numbers more than three SD away from the mean, from within each `ANALYTE` group.

While I realize that I should not remove outliers from a dataset normally, I would still like to know how to do it in R.

Here is a small portion of what my data look like:

[image: data]

Comment: Reproducible example, please. We don't have time to manually type your numbers to the R console.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230775/removing-dataframe-outliers-in-r-with-boxplot-stats

Answer (score 3):

It's subsetting by group, which can be done in different ways. With dplyr, you use `group_by` to set grouping, then `filter` to subset rows, passing it an expression that will calculate return `TRUE` for rows to keep, and `FALSE` for outliers.

For example, using `iris` and 2 standard deviations (everything is within 3):

```r
library(dplyr)

iris_clean <- iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    filter(abs(Petal.Length - mean(Petal.Length)) < 2*sd(Petal.Length))

iris_clean %>% count()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species        n
#>   <fct>      <int>
#> 1 setosa        46
#> 2 versicolor    47
#> 3 virginica     47
```

With a split-apply-combine approach in base R,

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(
    split(iris, iris$Species), 
    function(x) x[abs(x$Petal.Length - mean(x$Petal.Length)) < 2*sd(x$Petal.Length), ]
))
```

Comment: I deleted my answer (too similar to yours), but you could incorporate `scale` (i.e. `filter(abs(scale(Petal.Length))<2)` for compactness if you like

Comment: That's clever! I've stopped using `scale` unless I'm working with matrices already, but it's concise here.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I have a lot of analytes with a sd of 0, is there any way I can keep R from excluding these from being classified as outliers?

Comment: You can use `ifelse` or `case_when` within `filter`, like `filter(ifelse(sd(Petal.Length) == 0, TRUE, abs(Petal.Length - mean(Petal.Length)) < 2*sd(Petal.Length))` Or you may want to only chop for groups with a certain number of observations (`n()`) or unique values (`n_distinct`).